# Run process which "requires" elevation as non-elevated process or make it "think" it's "elevated"?

Tags: windows-8, uac, elevation

I have application which I don't want to tamper with my system settings, they require me to run them as administrator but I don't want that. I am 100% sure the applications will work without elevated access. Mainly programs which want to do anything in Program Files, but I install the programs into "Programs" folder (one which I created myself) so the applications don't need elevated access.

How can I run an application which requires elevation as non-elevated when on my admin account?

This would also be especially usefull for applications trying to install legit stuff + "a virus" (which cannot be detected by any AV software).

Comment: it seems to me you need a virtual machine.

Comment: This just became a shopping question!

Comment: @DaveRook please explain why, I don't get it :o (yes I have read [this](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/241/what-is-a-shopping-question))

Comment: because you specifically asked for software.

Comment: @ThePet - I suggest you remove your first comment which starts with *is there really no (freeware)program which allows to launch applications as non elevated*, then it will be back on topic :)

Comment: well any way, system related without third party software or with extra software, I don't care how, as long as it works :P

Comment: Done :) 8charsmore

Comment: You're basically looking to make `portable programs`, which will sacrifice file type associations and the like.  To avoid being off-topic myself, just google around for "how to make portable programs windows" and you may get somewhere.  I've never tried it, but it is a thing.

Comment: I'm not really looking into making 16GB games into a single .exe XD

Comment: is there seriously no way to say to windows: "DON'T run this application as an administrator, even when the app requests it, run it instead as a normal limited user"

Comment: @ThePet There is. Turn off UAC, and use non-admin account. There's no other option.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't hesitate to modify the exe file:

The exe file contains a manifest; search for something that looks similar to:

```
<requestedPrivileges>
  <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```

(Of course this will look different in the hex editor of your choice.) level could as well be "highestAvailable". Change it to "asInvoker".

(If you don't know how to patch an exe file, you should not try this. In no case use an editor like Notepad.)